# AWS database single column adds extremely much data

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I'm retrieving data from an AWS database using PgAdmin. This works well. The problem is that I have one column that I set to True after I retrieve the corresponding row, where originally it is set to Null. Doing so adds an enormous amount of data to my database.

I have checked that this is not due to other processes: it only happens when my program is running.
I am certain no rows are being added, I have checked the number of rows before and after and they're the same.

Furthermore, it only does this when changing specific tables, when I update other tables in the same database with the same process, the database size stays the same. It also does not always increase the database size, only once every couple changes does the total size increase.

How can changing a single boolean from Null to True add 0.1 MB to my database?

I'm using the following commands to check my database makeup:

**To get table sizes**

```
SELECT
    relname as Table,
    pg_total_relation_size(relid) As Size,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) as External Size
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

**To get number of rows:**

```
SELECT schemaname,relname,n_live_tup 
  FROM pg_stat_user_tables 
  ORDER BY n_live_tup DESC;
```

**To get database size:**

```
SELECT pg_database_size('mydatabasename')
```

Comment: Null is no data.
True is a byte (8 bits).

Plus one column, How many rows?

Comment: @AlexanderIngham I already added the column, now I'm just changing the values in the column from Null to True, one by one. It's about 20 million rows, but after retrieving 100.000 of those I already have over a GB of extra data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not changed that then your [`fillfactor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.6.3.2) is at 100% on the table since that is the default.

This means that every change in your table will mark the changed row as obsolete and will recreate the updated row. The issue could be even worse if you have indices on your table since those should be updated on every row change too. As you could imagine this hurts the `UPDATE` performance too.

So technically if you would read the whole table and update even the smallest column after reading the rows then it would double the table size when your `fillfactor` is 100.

What you can do is to `ALTER` your table lower the `fillfactor` on it, then `VACUUM` it:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table SET (fillfactor = 90);
VACUUM FULL your_table;
```

Of course with this step your table will be about `10%` bigger but Postgres will spare some space for your updates and it won't change its size with your process.

The reason why autovacuum helps is because it cleans the obsoleted rows periodically and therefore it will keep your table at the same size. But it puts a lot of pressure on your database. If you happen to know that you'll do operations like you described in the opening question then I would recommend tuning the `fillfactor` for your needs.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: I set fillfactor to 50%, and update every row then the total size should double before I vacuum it, and become the orginal size after vacuuming?

Comment: @Nathan if you set the rows to 50% and either do a `VACUUM` or a full table `UPDATE` then the size will double because it will reserve 50% of the size for later updates.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the question open  until tomorrow morning. If no other answers are posted I'll approve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ([source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-vacuum.html)):

> "In normal PostgreSQL operation, tuples that are deleted or obsoleted by an update are not physically removed from their table"

Furthermore, we did not always close the cursor which also increased database size while running.

One last problem is that we were running one huge query, not allowing the system to autovacuum properly. This problem is described in more detail [here](http://blog.lerner.co.il/in-postgresql-as-in-life-dont-wait-too-long-to-commit/)

Our solution was to re-approach the problem such that the rows did not have to be updated. Other solutions that we could think of but have not tried is to stop the process every once in a while allowing the autovacuum to work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean adds data? to all the data files? specifically to some files?

to get a precise answer you should supply more details, but generally speaking, any DB operation will add data to the transaction logs, and possibly other files.

Comment: Hi Ophir, what I mean is that the total database size increases. Strangely enough this only happens when I change specific tables.

I understand it always adds some data, but it currently adds such an exorbitant amount of space that something has to be wrong.